# How to package a "java-library" jar along with its dependencies before uploading the artifact?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a project setup in the following way

- root

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - app

    - src
    - build.gradle // this has plugins "java", "application"
  - lib

    - src
    - build.gradle // this has plugins "java-library"
  - anotherLib

    - src
    - build.gradle // this has plugins "java-library"
  - utility

    - src
    - build.gradle // this has plugins "java-library"

app/build.gradle has

```
implementation project(':lib')
```

lib/build.gradle has

```
api project(':utility')
runtimeOnly project(':anotherLib')
```

anotherLib/build.gradle has

```
implementation project(':utility')
```

When I run `./gradlew bootJar` then a fatJar for "app" is created with "lib", "anotherLib" and "utilitiy" inside it.

Now I have another project that needs "lib" as dependency. But the "lib" jar doesn't have the "utility" and "another" jar inside it. How can I create a artifact for "lib" and upload in such a way that other projects besides my "app" can add it as dependency in their gradle like `implementation "mygroup:lib:v1.0"` and they don't have to worry about or even know about "utility" or "anotherLib"?

If possible, I'd like to avoid uploading "utility" and "anotherLib" jars on their own. Can they be packaged inside "lib" jar? How to do that?

Also, if you think what I'm trying to do is just plain wrong, please let me know that as well

I'm using java 11, gradle 8.3, springboot gradle plugin 2.7.15

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to define the projects as modules and the root project as a multi-module project? then build each module on its own as a jar (and each jar including their own dependencies) or in your case you probably only need two modules app and lib. (app containing lib, and lib containing utility and another lib). what i said works for me on maven, but i dont use gradle, so i m not sure on the implementation for you